# how to use convert function sql (String to Date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I have imported a calendar table from datameer over to my sql server database. I am fairly new to SQL so I do not have the best understanding of the convert function. I have a calendar table with 5 columns (cal_month, cal_year, Toronto, Montreal, National_Avg). The data types are (nvarchar, nvarchar, numeric, numeric, float).

Example of a row in the table would be:

```
  Month  | Year | Toronto | Montreal | National Average
---------+------+---------+----------+------------------
 January | 2018 | 20      | 21       | 20.5
```

Below is my attempt at the convert function, my query is supposed to identify current month and -1 to grab the national average from the previous month so in this instance it would be for February 2018.

```
select convert(date, cal_month), convert(date,cal_year), National_Avg 
from dbo.CALENDAR
where month(cal_month) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
             and year(cal_year) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: SSMS (sql server management studio)

Comment: don't convert the month/year columns in the select or where clause, leave them as int (which is what your dateadd calls end up returning.

Comment: @AlexK. Could you give me an example so I can study and learn, much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manipulate the data in the table.  You just need to manipulate your search parameter `current_timestamp` to fit the data's data-types.

```
SELECT cal_month, cal_year, National_Avg 
FROM dbo.CALENDAR
WHERE cal_month = DATENAME(mm,   DATEADD(month,-1,current_timestamp))
  AND cal_year  = DATENAME(yyyy, DATEADD(month,-1,current_timestamp))
```

Comment: Thank you MatBailie, this query works ! much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is probably that you're trying to convert a month/year integer to a date.

Try:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, cal_month -1, DATEADD(year, cal_year-1900, 0)) 
from dbo.CALENDAR
```

Or if you need to get the month/year from today, try

```
DECLARE @oneMonthAgo datetime 
SET @oneMonthAgo = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 

DECLARE @cal_month int 
SET @cal_month = MONTH(@oneMonthAgo)

DECLARE @cal_year int 
SET @cal_year = YEAR(@oneMonthAgo)

SELECT National_Avg 
FROM dbo.CALENDAR
WHERE cal_year = @cal_year  AND cal_month  = @cal_month
```

Ah, just noticed you use the monthname - that is stupid, but anyway:

```
DECLARE @cal_month nvarchar(200)
SET @cal_month = DATENAME(month, @oneMonthAgo)
```

Everything else stays the same.

Or you could add a computed column to the calendar table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Calendar ADD MonthNum AS  

    CASE Month 
        WHEN 'January' THEN 1 
        WHEN 'February' THEN 2
        WHEN 'March' THEN 3 
        WHEN 'April' THEN 4 
        WHEN 'May' THEN 5
        WHEN 'June' THEN 6 
        WHEN 'July' THEN 7 
        WHEN 'August' THEN 8
        WHEN 'September' THEN 9
        WHEN 'October' THEN 10 
        WHEN 'November' THEN 11 
        WHEN 'December' THEN 12 
    END PERSISTED
```

That way, you do the lookup faster, as integer. 
Which will come in handy as the table fills and gets larger.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'January' to data type int.

Comment: This doesn't appear to match the OP's requirements at all.  `cal_month` is a string column and can't has `- 1` applied to it.  The OP needs to search for "last month", not manipulate the values in the table...

Comment: `cal_month` has `'January'`, `MONTH()` would return `1`.  `cal_year` has `'2018'` *(an NVARCHAR, according to the OP)*...

Comment: Comments like `that is stupid` earn a downvote from me.  If you want to elaborate on the up-sides and down-sides of the OP's implementation and your proposed alternatives, then fine.  As worded this just sounded derogatory.

Comment: @MatBailie: Added a proposed alternative. I disagree with political correctness - it's better to say what you think - even if it may be upsetting others. But you're right on that I should add an alternatives, if I do that. So i did.